# verifiedEmail AOL OpenID

Tags: python, openid, rpxnow

I can't seem to fetch the verifiedEmail field when trying to login to AOLs OpenID on my site. Every other provider that I know of provides this property, but not AOL.

I realize that AOL somehow uses an old OpenID version, although is it feasible to just assume that their e-mail ends in @aol.com? I'm using the RPXNow library with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that OpenID lets the user decide how much information to "share" during the login process.  I can't say that I am an expert on the subject, but I know that my identity at myopenid.com lets me specify precisely what information to make available.

Is it possible that the AOL default is to share nothing?  If this is the case, then you may want to do an email authorization directly with the user if the OpenID provider doesn't seem to have the information.  OpenID doesn't mandate that this information is available so I would assume that you will have to handle the case of it not being there in application code.

Comment: So you are saying that the best solution is to simply ask them for a verification email after they sign-in?

Comment: If one is not provided with the OpenID profile, then I would let the user tell you what account to use. It's a nice general solution to the problem. You can default the form to _user_@aol.com in this case. If you want to go the extra yard, then inform the user that this can be avoided by configuring their OpenID profile information.